# CSS Media Query Won't Work

Tags: css, responsive-design

I keep trying to do a media query in my CSS doc doing something like:

```
@media screen and (max-device-width: 480px) { /*css here*/}
```

but it won't work when I test it on an iPhone. I've tried changing the sizes and using the portrait/landscape feature, but still nothing. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you can use max-width also, try with it
@media screen and (max-width: 250px)

Comment: Try switching it to `max-width`: http://jsfiddle.net/z7pN9/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I always call mine when I link the CSS in the head of the HTML.

An example from a current page I'm working on:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-width: 500px)" href="css/mobile.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen and (min-device-width: 501px)" href="css/main.css" />
```

This selects the CSS doc that will be loaded right from the start instead of selecting styles after the CSS document is loaded (reduces number of HTTP requests)

When doing this within the CSS document itself, you should generally replace `max-device-width` with `max-width`.

Comment: You are adding extra HTTP requests by separating the CSS files -- better to just combine the two unless there is a good reason for spitting them.

Comment: This worked for me, I was able to copy it in and just change the href attribute

Comment: This is actually the worst way you can handle media queries.  Every device will download *all* media queries, even if they do not currently meet the media query requirements.

Comment: Interesting...so it's a bit of a misnomer if it doesn't selectively load based on the parameters in the media attribute

Comment: I've seen an article from the Webkit team talking about how they prioritize downloading CSS files that will apply immediately, but yeah, they're all downloaded eventually.  You wouldn't want to wait for the styles to download if you rotate your handheld, would you?  Same applies for printing.

Comment: I had not heard that before...thanks for the info!

Comment: Rearding downloading, see http://scottjehl.github.io/CSS-Download-Tests/

Answer (score 91):

Check that you have

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

in the head of your doc

Comment: This is important. Because without viewport tag media queries don't work at all.

Comment: This should be the correct answer

Answer (score 6):

Use `"max-width"` instead of `"max-device-width"` which is fixed per device.

Comment: This isn't really relevant for handheld devices where max-width and max-device-width are the same.  It only matters for desktop where the browser doesn't have to be maximized.

Comment: This helped me out thanks. I was looking in a browser though. I don't see why you wouldn't use it instead anyway, I mean using a desktop size interface on a shrunken desktop screen doesn't seem efficient when you can just use the max-width for both instead.

Answer (score 6):

this is a samples media query css

```
/************************************************************************************
smaller than 980
*************************************************************************************/
@media screen and (max-width: 980px) {
your css here
}

/************************************************************************************
smaller than 650
*************************************************************************************/
@media screen and (max-width: 650px) {
your css here
}
/************************************************************************************
smaller than 560
*************************************************************************************/
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
your css here
}
```

Hard to understand as you have not provided the code..but the common mistake people do it by not adding this meta data

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but I think the `max-device-width` of an iphone is 640px. Give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

```
@media only screen and (min-width : 480px) {

}
```

It seems to work fine in both Android and iPhone.